# Previewing layer on GeoServer instead of downloading WMS file?

Tags: geoserver, wms

I am new to Geoserver 2.8.0. I just installed it and passed some layers from PostGIS.

I used the existing, default `cite` workspace, then added a `myProject` Store, with type `PostGIS`. I loaded the layers and set the `Bounding Boxes`, I enabled `Response Cache Headers`, set some default styles and set the min/max zoom levels from 0 to6.

In this new Geoserver interface, how can I set or at least check what type of layer is this? Is it a `WMS`, a `WFS`? My PostGIS layers are some OSM data, that I converted and saved on PostGIS

My main question is that I can preview the `planet_osm_line`, `planet_osm_road` and `planet_osm_point` but not the `planet_osm_polygon`. When I hit OpenLayers to preview it in Geoserver, instead of opening a new tab with OpenLayers it automatically downloads a `wms`  file.

How do I fix this? Is there something wrong with my settings?

Comment: Save the "wms" file on disk and open it with a text editor. I bet it contains an error message that hopefully explains what is wrong with your planet_osm_polygon layer. When it comes to services, you can access your data both via WMS as rendered maps and via WFS as vector data.

Comment: @user30184 Thanks. Check my answer. Also, turn your comment to an ansewer, so I can upvote you

Comment: Your answer is just fine. Just add this piece of information into it: according to WMS 1.x standard the MIME-type of the service exception report is `application/vnd.ogc.se_xml`. Browsers typically do not recognize that MIME type and they suggest to save the response on disk instead of showing it directly. Here is an URL to test with (format=image/foo will lead to an error) http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/wms?SERVICE=WMS&REQUEST=GetMap&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&WIDTH=459&HEIGHT=351&LAYERS=osm%3Aosm&TRANSPARENT=TRUE&FORMAT=image/foo&BBOX=-122.893,49.162,-122.889,49.165&SRS=EPSG:4326&STYLES=

Answer (score 9):

Yes, user30184 is right. I just opened the `wms` file and says

```
     java.io.IOException: No such resource: generic.sld
```

No such resource: generic.sld

So I went back to Geoserver and I changed the default style of the layer from "generic" to "giant_polygon", or whatever works for you

login to geoserver, click layers, choose the problematic layer, select the "Publishing" card and then change the style from the drop down Default Style menu

Thanks

Comment: Alternatively, you could define the style named "generic".

Comment: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/geoserver/geoserver/master/src/main/src/test/java/org/geoserver/data/test/generic.sld